# Online text editor not working with my javascript code

Tags: javascript, textarea

I have an online text editor "CKEditor" working by reference to it and making a specific class name "ckeditor" for the textarea that I want the editor to work with, the editor works well with the textarea but once I add the textarea by java script function it shows the textarea without the editor, here is the java script code:

```
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.6.2/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script>
function myFunction(){
    var target = document.getElementById("target"); 
    target.innerHTML = '<textarea name="editor1" class="ckeditor"></textarea>';
}
</script>
```

this is the html code:

```
<!--the editor works with this textarea-->
<textarea name="editor1" class="ckeditor"></textarea>

<button onClick="myFunction()">runFunction</button>
<!--the div I want java script to place the editor by clicking the above button-->
<div id="target">some text</div>
```

any solution?

Comment: because ckeditor does not know you added an element, you need to tell it you added it.

Comment: Quentin thanks, I tried to add the  CKEDITOR.replace() method but it still not working, or it should working with the class name only as the one below, if you can write the code for me.

Comment: Could you not comment on the answer?? Did you add the id to the element? Did you call the line after you set the innerHTML?

Comment: I've tried almost everything but it's not working for me at all, maybe I write the wrong syntax or something, I don't know, is there any similar way to achieve this code.

Comment: `target.innerHTML = ''<textarea id="editor1" ...";  CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_installation-section-adding-ckeditor-to-your-page):

> ```
> Use the CKEDITOR.replace() method to replace the existing <textarea> element with CKEditor.
> ```

Where the example code shows:

> ```
> CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' )
> ```

Where `editor1` is the ID of a textarea in the document.

So give the textarea an ID, and then call that function after you add it to the document.